# Next-Auth Session is flickering when reloading

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have a problem with next-auth and the session while being logged in. When I reload a page the session is - for my understanding - fully reloading. This means that information in the navbar changes with every reload. That not the biggest problem but isn't the nicesest ux.

Is there a way to stop this from "flickering"?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
"use client"
import { Fragment } from 'react'
import { Disclosure, Menu, Transition } from '@headlessui/react'
import { Bars3Icon, BellIcon, XMarkIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'
import { useSession, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';
import Link from 'next/link'

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Home', href: '/', current: true },
  { name: 'Paycheck', href: '/paycheck', current: false },
  { name: 'About', href: '/about', current: false },
]

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}

export default function NavBar() {

  const { data: session } = useSession()
  const userId = session?.user?.id
  const userName = session?.user?.name


  return (
    <Disclosure as="nav" className="bg-gray-800">
      {({ open }) => (
        <>
          <div className="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">
              <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                <Disclosure.Button className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
                  <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                  {open ? (
                    <XMarkIcon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  ) : (
                    <Bars3Icon className="block h-6 w-6" aria-hidden="true" />
                  )}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
                <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center">
                  <p className='text-white'>Overview</p>
                </div>
                <div className="hidden sm:ml-6 sm:block">
                  <div className="flex space-x-4">
                    {navigation.map((item) => (
                      <a
                        key={item.name}
                        href={item.href}
                        className={classNames(
                          item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                          'rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium'
                        )}
                        aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </a>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
              {session ? (
                <div className="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-2 sm:static sm:inset-auto sm:ml-6 sm:pr-0">
                <div className="ml-3 relative text-white">
                  {userName? userName : "User"}
                </div>

                <Menu as="div" className="relative ml-3">
                    <div>
                    <Menu.Button className="flex rounded-full bg-white text-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-white focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-gray-800">
                        <span className="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                        <img
                        className="h-8 w-8 rounded-full"
                        src={session.user.image? session.user.image : "@/public/user.png"}
                        alt=""
                        />
                    </Menu.Button>
                    </div>
                    <Transition
                    as={Fragment}
                    enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                    enterFrom="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    enterTo="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                    leaveFrom="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                    leaveTo="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                    >
                    <Menu.Items className="absolute right-0 z-10 mt-2 w-48 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-1 shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                        <Menu.Item>
                        {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                            href={"/user/" + userId}
                            className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                            >
                            Your Profile
                            </a>
                        )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item>
                        {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                            href={"/user/" + userId + "/settings"}
                            className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-gray-700')}
                            >
                            Settings
                            </a>
                        )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                        <Menu.Item>
                        {({ active }) => (
                            <a
                            href="#"
                            onClick={() => signOut()}
                            className={classNames(active ? 'bg-gray-100' : '', 'block px-4 py-2 text-sm text-red-400')}
                            >
                            Sign out
                            </a>
                        )}
                        </Menu.Item>
                    </Menu.Items>
                    </Transition>
                </Menu>
              </div>
              ) : ( 
                <div className=''>
                <Link href={"/user/login"} style={{ width: '160px' }} className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-amber-600 rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium">
                  Log In
                </Link>
                <Link href={"/user/register"} style={{ width: '160px' }} className="text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-amber-600 rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium">
                  Register
                </Link>
              </div> 
                
              )}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <Disclosure.Panel className="sm:hidden">
            <div className="space-y-1 px-2 pb-3 pt-2">
              {navigation.map((item) => (
                <Disclosure.Button
                  key={item.name}
                  as="a"
                  href={item.href}
                  className={classNames(
                    item.current ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white',
                    'block rounded-md px-3 py-2 text-base font-medium'
                  )}
                  aria-current={item.current ? 'page' : undefined}
                >
                  {item.name}
                </Disclosure.Button>
              ))}
            </div>
          </Disclosure.Panel>
        </>
      )}
    </Disclosure>
  )
}
```